# considerations to keep browser running on server/cloud to track real time data

Tags: selenium, web-crawler, puppeteer, browser-automation, playwright

I'm trying to track a slack channel I'm part of but I don't wanna/can install slack apps, so I thought about browser automation and keep a browser open and running with playwright/selenium. I'm unsure of the implications of something like this, what to watch for and would it be expensive?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out https://pptr.dev/ or http://playwright.dev in headless mode running locally/server.
https://docs.browserless.io/ is an option if you want something big